# Check registered user in flutter signup php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dart, flutter

I have flutter app with user registration check by php & mysql. I'm searching around in php like :

```
 $sqlUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con ,$sqlUser);
    $numUsers = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    if($numUsers > 0) {
        echo "User already exists<br/>";
    }
```

and this is my php script for creating user :

```
 <?php
 require_once 'connectdb.php';

  $user_id= $_POST['id'];
  $username = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $nama = $_POST['name'];
  $nik = $_POST['nik'];
  $lahir = $_POST['born'];
  $tentang = $_POST['about'];
  $pengalaman = $_POST['exp'];
  $linkedin = $_POST['linkedin'];


$query="INSERT INTO user_info(id, email, password, name, nik, born, about, exp,linkedin)
     VALUES ('$user_id','$username','$password','$name','$nik', '$born', '$about', '$exp', '$linkedin')";
    $exeQuery = mysqli_query($con, $query) ;

     if($exeQuery){
     echo (json_encode(array('code' =>1, 'message' => 'Ajouter avec succée')));
}else {echo(json_encode(array('code' =>2, 'message' => 'Non Terminer')));
 }


 ?>
```

my flutter sign up :

```
void _register() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    var url = "url/newuser.php";

    await http.post(url, body: {
      "email": _emailController.text,
      "password": _passwordController.text,
      "name": _nameController.text,
      "nik": _nikController.text,
    });
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    onCreatedAccount();
    //print(_adresseController.text);
  }
```

but how do i pass it to my flutter app, so my app knows that it has registered email/user?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!  [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks, i just use it for experimental purpose, and did not get a chance for optimizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use Dio library [Flutter Dio Library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio#-installing-tab-) and use the response to get data from server.

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
FormData formData = new FormData.from({
  "email": _emailController.text,
  "password": _passwordController.text,
  "name": _nameController.text,
  "nik": _nikController.text,
});
dio
    .post("http://yoururl.com/register.php",
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
            method: 'POST',
            responseType: ResponseType.PLAIN // or ResponseType.JSON
            ))
    .timeout(Duration(seconds: 15))
    .then((response) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.data);
  if (data['code'] == '1') {
       //success code
  }else{
      //error code
  }
```

and in the server:

```
$response = array();
//do sql test and storing
if(success){
    $response['code'] = '1';
    $response['message'] = 'success message.';
}else{
    $response['code'] = '2';
    $response['message'] = 'error message.';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have some id with auto increment in your database, than you can use some loop to take all the value of username field and save the result in some array data, after that you can validate the result of that data array with your username controller.

```
var data = [];
for (int i = 0; i < int.parse(snapshot.data[snapshot.data.length - 1]['id']); i++) {
    data.addAll({snapshot.data[i]['username']});
}

if (data.contains(contUsername.text) == true) {
   showToastAlert("Username is already taken!");
} else {
   addUser();
}
```

But, if you want to delete some account, you need to improve your code with reset value auto increment, or you can just change that deleted username value to null for replace any new user value or in other way you can make some field that can be used for validate their account is still active (they can be logged in) or not (they can't be logged in) this is will helping user for restore their account.

or you can only use the length of data for more simple resolve your case like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++);
```

Hopefully this can be useful.